# Android did not recognise my android 7inch tablet 3.2 honeyComb

Tags: android, eclipse

My Android eclipse did not recognizing my 7 inch android tablet. its installing and showing usb icon on window but when i tried to run my application the device is not showing on eclipse.

Comment: have you enabled **usb debugging**??

Comment: Are u sure install adb driver for your tablet?

Comment: I guess eclipse does'nt support some the tablet i think u need to make changes in your eclipse to get your tablet going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to update your adb_usb.ini to include the USB ID of your device and/or install a driver if you're on Windows.

I had to this when I started developing for Kindle Fire.

Here's a page of instructions for Archos: http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html?country=us&lang=en  You can probably find a similar page for your manufacturer.

After that, you need to stop adb and restart it and then you should be able to see your device.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [THIS LINK](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

I think you are facing problems in setting up your system for development, so take a look at step 3 on above link.

> a. Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.
>   Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

> b.Now execute:
>   chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

And if you are on ubuntu, [THIS LINK](http://dimitar.me/how-to-connect-your-android-phone-to-ubuntu-to-do-developmenttestinginstallations-or-tethering/) will help you.

Good luck!